# World color is a weird pink color in viewport shader, disabling ‘scene world’ fixes it but still shows up in render. It is not a missing texture

Tags: rendering, objects, lighting, color, world

[image]

It is not a missing texture. Here’s an image of my world shader. Even if I change the image or remove it entirely, everything is still pink. It’s like it’s one big lighting somewhere shining pink, even on new imported objects or just creating new objects. How do I fix this? And again, it’s not a missing texture, I made sure of that[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your Image Texture:

[image: Image Texture highlighting the Color Space]

You should change "Non-Color" to "sRGB".