# All my model renders are shown in pink, but there is no missing texture

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation

My actual model is like this:
[image]

But when I render it as an animation, everything is displayed in pink:
[image]

I tried the following solution, but unfortunately I could not solve it with it:
[World color is a weird pink color in viewport shader, disabling ‘scene world’ fixes it but still shows up in render. It is not a missing texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249336/)

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? Only keep 2 or 3 objects: https://blend-exchange.com/